# Login with session variables undefined

Tags: php, session, variables, if-statement, authentication

I will try and explain my situation as best as i can, ive had a look at a few questions on here, but none seem to answer my problem.

Ive created a website using my own custom MVC framework, which works well.

I have a simple login command which also works, it correctly returns a customerID and their name provided their email and password are correct.

once they have been verified, rather than returning the data, i simply set a couple of session variables, so when they are returned to the home page (now logged in via session variables), they are shown their name and items in cart, instead of "welcome visitor".

```
        if($record = $stmt->fetch())
        {   
            $_SESSION["Name"] = $record["FirstName"];   
            $_SESSION["CustomerID"] = $record["ID"];        
            $_SESSION["LoginStatus"] = true;
            $response->SetViewName("DefaultView"); // Login Success, back to homepage               
        }
        else
        {
            $response->SetViewName("LoginView"); // Login Failure, back to login view   
        }
```

In my header.php file, i have the html code which shows the corresponding welcome message, if they are a visitor, they are shown visitor, if not ($_SESSION["LoginStatus"] == true) they are shown their name and items in cart...

```
            <?php
            if($_SESSION["LoginStatus"] == false) // if visitor
            {
                echo '<p class="welcome">Welcome visitor, please <a href="Index.php?cmd=Login">log in</a> or <a href="Index.php?cmd=Register">register</a></p>';
            }
            else if($_SESSION["LoginStatus"] == true) // if logged in
            {
                echo "<p class='welcome'>Welcome back ".$_SESSION["Name"].", you have ".$_SESSION["ItemsInCart"]." items in your cart</p>";
            }
            ?>
```

So when a new user comes to the website, they have a session started, but when the LoginStatus variable is checked, it throws an error, due to being undefined, but if i define it just below the session is started, when the user logs in, the variable is always false, and they are never shown their name or items in cart.

Comment: He says in the text, a session is started. But where is it started? in which file?

Comment: Yep, session is started at the top of my header file, right above <html>

Comment: and what does the error say?

Comment: its just a "catch-22" situation, i cant check the login status, because its not defined, if i define it, i have to set it as false, if i do that, when theyve logged in, it will go from true back to false and they wont be logged in

Comment: look at my answer of using isset on the session variable, it checks if a variable has been set yet or not

Comment: well if its right above the <html> tag then its in the wrong place, it needs to be above all your other php code. Unless your account checking code is mixed in with your html code ...

Comment: Problem fixed, see comment at the bottom, thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use a if checking

`isset($_SESSION["LoginStatus"])`

before checking its value, if it is set then check its value, if its not set then they arent logged in at all

Comment: after i log in, this returns false, even though in my command i set the session variable as "true"

Comment: Then you are not starting your session correctly, before setting the session variable.

Answer (score 0):

When no user is logged in, $_SESSION[LoginSatus"] is empty.

You will have to set it to false in your first script or checking if it's empty/isset in the 2nd script.

Comment: He shouldnt set it to false in the first script, this would cause the user to be logged out accidentally if they were logged in and for some reason went to that first script. He would still have to do the check in the first script to prevent this

Comment: I agree. Checking with isset is way better. And I think isset will solve his undefined problem.

Comment: Ok, so to check if it actually contains anything after loggin in, i set it to "SOMETHING", and when i first visit the homepage, i check if it is set, if its not, i set it to "NOTHING". when i echo it out straight away, the variable is null, it contains literally nothing. when i log in, it still contains nothing. so in both cases the variable is not being set...

Comment: Then I'm wondering if you session is correctly set... I tried your script and for me it works fine.

Comment: Hello everyone - OP here, i cannot answer my own question as im relatively new to the site.


Everyones responses work flawlessly, the problem lied within my MVC framework, When i click a link, it runs a command, which in return sends a response to the page i set it to go to.

the problem was i cannot set session variables in my command, as they are a class, and not a php script running on any page. so in effect, they are non-existent to the pages.

Comment: I fixed the problem by simply adding the login status to the response variable, which gets sent to the new view, the view then sets the session variable and in turn, logs me in correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following right after `session_start();`

```
    if(!isset($_SESSION["LoginStatus")){
         $_SESSION["LoginStatus"] = false;
    }
```

Should fix the problem if I have understood it right.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to use empty tag to check like:

```
if(!empty($_SESSION["LoginStatus"])){

   code to do as loggined user
 }else{
    code to 
  }
```